# DGrid Editor - Changing the Displayed Value when Trying to Edit a Text Cell

Tags: javascript, text, dojo, editor, dgrid

I'm using a DGrid editor column to edit the contents of a store. Of the fields that I want to be able to edit, one is an object. When I click on the field to edit it, what I want is for the value displayed in the editor to match the value displayed by the grid when not editing. The cell formatting just shows the value of the object, but when I click on the field to edit it, instead of the object's value, I instead the field is populated with '[object Object]'. I can still edit it (though the results of doing so is that the field will display 'undefined' until I refresh the page, but I could just force a refresh after the change), but can't seem to get it to show what I want.
Here's the set up code:

```
 // build the store
                this.postStore = Observable(Memory({
                    data: posts
                }));

                var formatCategory = function(object, data, cell) {
                    cell.innerHTML = object.category.value;
                };

                var formatAuthor = function(object, data, cell) {
                    cell.innerHTML = object.author.value;
                };

                var formatDate = function(object, data, cell) {
                    cell.innerHTML = new Date(object.dateCreated).toISOString();
                };

                // the columns displayed in the grid
                var columns = [
                    selector({
                        field: 'checkbox',
                        label: ' ',
                        selectorType: 'radio',
                        width:33
                    }),
                    {
                        label: "Author",
                        field: "author",
                        width: 120,
                        renderCell: formatAuthor
                    },
                    editor({
                        label: "Title",
                        field: "title",
                        editor: "text",
                        editOn: "click",
                        width: 200
                    }),
                    editor({
                        label: "Text",
                        field: "text",
                        editor: "text",
                        editOn: "click",
                        width:500
                    }, Textarea),
                    editor({
                        label: "Category",
                        field: "category",
                        editor: "text",
                        editOn: "click",
                        width: 150,
                        renderCell: formatCategory
                    }),
                    {
                        label: "Date",
                        field: "date",
                        renderCell: formatDate,
                        width: 120
                    }
                ];

                if (this.postGrid) {
                    this.postGrid.set("store", this.postStore);
                } else {
                    var SelectionGrid = new declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection, Keyboard, editor, selector, DijitRegistry, ColumnResizer]);
                    this.postGrid = new SelectionGrid({
                        store: this.postStore,
                        columns: columns,
                        selectionMode: 'none',
                        sort: [{attribute: "date", descending: false}]
                    }, this.postGridDiv);
                    this.postGrid.startup();

                    this.postGrid.on("dgrid-select, dgrid-deselect", lang.hitch(this, this._postSelected));

                    this.postGrid.on("dgrid-datachange", lang.hitch(this, function(evt){
                        var cell = this.postGrid.cell(evt);
                        var post = cell.row.data;

                        if (cell.column.field === "title") {
                            post.title = evt.value;
                        } else if (cell.column.field === "text") {
                            post.text = evt.value;
                        } else if (cell.column.field === "category") {
                            post.category.value = evt.value;
                        }

                        this._updatePost(post);
                    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining a `renderCell` function, define a `get` function (which is used to transform the value before it is even sent to `renderCell`) and a `set` function (which is used to transform data back before it's sent to a store when saving edits).

Something like:

```
get: function (object) {
    return object.category.value;
},
set: function (object) {
    return { value: object.category };
}
```

See also the [documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/dev-0.4/doc/components/core-components/Grid.md#column-definition-properties).

Comment: Thanks for the examples. The 'get' works fine, but for some reason the 'set' function never gets called. Do you know off hand while that would be?

Comment: The `set` function should get called any time you call `grid.save()` (or any time an editor loses focus if `autosave` is set to `true` on the column).  That's when the modified item will be `put` back into the store.

Comment: So forgot to mention this, but in the end, setting the autosave to true and setting the get pretty much fixed everything. I didn't need the set method, and even with save it never got called.